# python pandas parse datetime string with months names

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, pandas

Can someone point me to a format or a code snippet to parse date in format like

```
04SEP12:00:00:00
```

That `%dd%mm%YY:%HH:%MM:%SS` doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use format string: `'%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S'` and pass this as the format for [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime), you can find the format options in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
In [73]:

pd.to_datetime('04SEP12:00:00:00', format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S')
Out[73]:
Timestamp('2012-09-04 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way is simply do:

```
pd.to_datetime("May 15, 2016", infer_datetime_format=True)

>>>Timestamp('2016-05-15 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

As another example,

```
pd.to_datetime("May 15, 2016", format="%b %d, %Y")
>>>Timestamp('2016-05-15 00:00:00')
```

Use %b for the month names.