# Convert a string "ddMONyyyy" onto date in Python

Tags: python, string, date

I have the following pd data `df` that includes one string column `mydate`

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'mydate': ['01JAN2009','20FEB2013','13MAR2010','01APR2012', '20MAY2013', '18JUN2018', '10JUL2002', '30AUG2000', '15SEP2001', '30OCT1999',
                 '04NOV2020', '23DEC1995']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['mydate'])
```

I need to convert `mydate` into date type and store it in a new column `mydate2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas parse datetime string with months names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332984/python-pandas-parse-datetime-string-with-months-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'mydate': ['01JAN2009','20FEB2013','13MAR2010','01APR2012', '20MAY2013', '18JUN2018', '10JUL2002', '30AUG2000', '15SEP2001', '30OCT1999',
                 '04NOV2020', '23DEC1995']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['mydate'])

df['mydate2']=pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       mydate    mydate2
0   01JAN2009 2009-01-01
1   20FEB2013 2013-02-20
2   13MAR2010 2010-03-13
3   01APR2012 2012-04-01
4   20MAY2013 2013-05-20
5   18JUN2018 2018-06-18
6   10JUL2002 2002-07-10
7   30AUG2000 2000-08-30
8   15SEP2001 2001-09-15
9   30OCT1999 1999-10-30
10  04NOV2020 2020-11-04
11  23DEC1995 1995-12-23
```