# Error while converting string to date time using datetime.strptime()

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

pickle["CSE_TS_SAMPLING"].head(2)

output:
0    02-DEC-2020 20:16:09
1    03-DEC-2020 03:43:33
Name: CSE_TS_SAMPLING, dtype: object

from datetime import datetime
def convert_date(x):
return datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
pickle["sample_date"]=pickle["CSE_TS_SAMPLING"].apply(lambda x:convert_date(x))

error:
time data '02-DEC-2020 20:16:09' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas parse datetime string with months names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332984/python-pandas-parse-datetime-string-with-months-names)

Answer (score 1):

`%m` is the month 01 through 12.  `%b` would match your date of "DEC" (note, `%b` depends on locale).